# How to get a filetype icon in Windows using C/C++?

Tags: c++, windows

I am looking for a C/C++ code which can get icon for a given filetype (eg. .doc, .pdf) on Windows. I need to make an application which will display a list of files and I need to have the file icons corresponding to those files.

I have seen C# code for the same but I have never worked with C# and don't think that I can use the same code for my use.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301425.aspx

So you basically call [`SHGetFileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179%28VS.85%29.aspx) with SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES and any file name/path (it doesn't matter if it doesn't exist), and it writes the filetype info to a [`SHFILEINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759792%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks tiftik.
It appears to be a very old link (Nov 2000). Do you think this method will still work?
Also, I couldn't download the code for the small application that was made by the author, do you have the source code to try out this approach.
I am very new to C++ programming and don't know how to proceed with this information and make an application like the one made by the author. Could you please help.

Comment: Windows has a well-deserved reputation for interface stability. These interfaces still work in Windows 7, and there's no announcement of their withdrawal. So you can expect them to work well past 2020.

Comment: It has to work, MSDN doesn't say anything about the function being deprecated. You need to include windows.h and Shellapi.h in your code and tell the compiler/linker to use Shell32.lib.